# How to avoid duplicating assigned materials when duplicating a mesh?

Tags: materials

how can I prevent Blender 2.8 from duplicating materials every time (?) I duplicate a mesh.

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust it in the Preferences>Editing>Duplicate Data. In factory settings it's unchecked and it doesn't duplicate the material for me.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is unchecked here too. Is there a different behaviour between shift + D (duplicate) and cmd + V (copy)?

Comment: I never used the ctrl+c, ctrl+v. Now I tried it and it duplicates the material for me too, but the shift+d doesn't.